# Pandas column fill N/As with rolling mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'rate': [0.5,0.4,0.5,np.nan,np.nan],
                  })
```

I'd like to replace NaNs in `rate` column with rolling mean of previous 3 values.

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rolling` to replace `isna()` values.

```
df.loc[df.rate.isna(),'rate'] = df['rate'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Comment: I updated the question to use `np.nan` instead of `N/A`. could you please modify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try  round rolling mean except remember the [python behaviour of round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) which is `the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float`

```
df =df.assign(rate=np.where(df['rate'].isna(),round(df['rate'].rolling(3,1).mean(),1),df['rate']))
```

Comment: how does this apply only to `np.nan`?

Comment: sme bad, edited for you